# Java Blocks, Closures, Lambdas... simply explained

Tags: java, lambda, closures, block

For those who ever wrote in C, C++ or ObjectiveC, understand Blocks is very simple. Why it's so difficult to get the concept in Java (8)?

I will answer my question!

Comment: This is not a real question - it's not asking about a specific problem.

Comment: It's also too broad, and the answer is inaccurate in several places.

Comment: Java is based on C and C++ so the behaviour of a `{ }` is much the same.  Its not clear what your doubt is.

Answer (score 2):

**Block**

Just a list of statements surrounded by curly braces.  That's all.  A block is executed by executing its individual statements in sequence.  It's nothing like the thing called a "block" in, for example, the Ruby programming language.

**Closure**

Java does not have closures, but it has something that looks like one:

```
int limit = ...;

Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i=0 ; i<limit ; i++) { ... }
    }
});
```

That may *look* like the run() method refers to the variable `limit` in the outer scope, but it won't compile unless the variable `limit` is effectively immutable.  What's really happening here is that the anonymous inner class has a *member variable* named `limit`, and a hidden constructor that takes an *argument* named `limit`, and the value is supplied to the constructor by *copying* the value of `limit` from the surrounding scope.

**Lambda**

More smoke and mirrors.  The value of a lambda expression in Java is not a function:  It's an instance of an anonymous inner class that implements a *functional interface*.  The same code that I wrote above could be written more concisely as a Java lambda expression:

```
int limit = ...;
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
    for (int i=0 ; i<limit ; i++) { ... }
});
```

Java8 introduces the idea of an `@Functional` interface type which must declare exactly one method.  In this case, they've retconned the `java.lang.Runnable` class to be `@Functional`

When the compiler reads the code above, it knows to make the anonymous class implement the `Runnable` interface because that's the only type that is accepted by the `Thread` constructor, and it knows that the body of the lambda should become the `run()` method, because that's the only method declared by `Runnable.`

Comment: Thanks James for you contribution.
I didn't speak about that kind of blocks but Blocks as Apple added them in C, C++ and Objective-C (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_%28C_language_extension%29) that means Closures or Lambdas.
So what you explain is not the kind of "blocks" functionalities I spoke about. I missed to explain correctly my mind.

Answer (score -2):

All you need to understand is “type”.

A variable has a type. Eg:

```
int i, double d…
```

An object has a type (a class). Eg:

```
String s, Number n, Object o, MyClass m…
```

A function has a type. Eg:

```
void function () <= this type is: a function with no return and no param.
void function (type param) <= this type is: a function with no return with a param of type ‘type’
type function (type param) <= this type is: a function with a return of type ‘type’ and a param of type ‘type’
```

What is a block/closure/lambda?

It is basically a local function of a given type passed to an other function as parameter.

So we heard: a function that takes a function of a given type as parameter.
And the function which receive the function and launches it!

The main usage is: CallBack and Comparaison functions. But the dream up is open.

We can draw that as:

```
type function(type function_param) {
    excute the function_param
}
```

How to say this in Java.

1/ declare the type of the block/closure/lambda

2/ create the function (in a class or not) which get that kind of type as param

3/ create the local function of the type of the block/closure/lambda

4/ pass it as param to the function which use it.

Eg:

```
// 1 declaring the type of block/closure/lambda
interface CallBack {
    public int function(String string);
}

class MyClass {
    private String name;
    MyClass(String name) { this.name = name; }
    void display () { System.out.println(this.name); }

   // 2 creating the function that which that kind of type as param
    int myFunction(CallBack funcCallBack) {
        return funcCallBack.function(name);
    }
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       // 3 Create the local function of the type of the block/closure/lambda
        CallBack message = (String string) -> {
            System.out.println("Message: "+string);
            return 1;
       };

        MyClass mc = new MyClass("MyClass");
        mc.display();

        // 4 pass it as param to the function which use it.
        int res = mc.myFunction(message);
        System.out.println(res);

    }
}
```

output

MyClass

Message: MyClass

1